# Is there any JDBC Type 4 driver for DB2 v6?

Tags: jdbc, db2

Does DB2 UDB v6 supports JDBC Type 4 drivers?

Where can I get that JDBC Type 4 driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think yes but not very sure. As V6 is out of support, most likely you would not be able to get it from IBM. You may want to check internally to see if they have any copies of the drivers. Check the below link for some useful information
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp